# Wrapping with Dependency Properties

Tags: wpf, data-binding, windowsformshost, dependency-properties

I've got a Windows Forms control that I'm wrapping with a `WindowsFormsHost`-derived class to access WPF's data binding functionality. The Forms control exposes properties that indicate its state, along with the standard property-changed event notifier.

For example, a `Zoom` property on the Forms control is accompanied with a `ZoomChanged` event. In the `WindowsFormsHost` wrapper, I'm using a `DependencyProperty` to represent the underlying Windows Forms control property. Binding works as expected going to the control using a `PropertyMetaData` assignment callback; however, I'm not sure how to correctly propagate property changes from the wrapped control back out to binding subscribers (i.e., the Windows Form control changes its `Zoom` property and raises the `ZoomChanged` event). Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Should I be using a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defaulted the Zoom dependency property to use two-way binding and everything works. D'oh!